# Is Java thread id unique across multiple thread pools?

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool, executorservice

I have multiple thread pools running each with 4 threads. Each thread locks some common resource based on a unique ID they provide. I am using `Thread.currentThread().getId()` as unique ID to lock and release resources.

I read in Thread class that thread ID is just a long number that is incremented and allocated, also it may be reused once a thread is terminated. But it does not mention anything regarding its behavior in thread pools.

Is the thread ID guaranteed to be unique among threads that are part of different thread pools?

Comment: I would assume so. A Thread pool is a just a collection of pools that is being managed in some way, but in the end they are just threads and their IDs should be unique.

Comment: Not directly related, but you might consider using [Semaphore](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html)s for controlling access to resources from within threads. [Example](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/semaphore-in-java/)

Comment: @RandyCasburn Semaphores does not fit my use case. The resources I lock are reusable objects from an object pool and I have to track some statistics including the memory footprint of every thread.

Comment: @Divanshu - got it.

Answer (score 1):

Thread ID is unique; but you need to beware that once the thread terminates JVM may reuse the thread ID.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#getId--

Comment: Oh, hit the send too soon. Then yes, again according to javadocs id is unique (though it may be reused once the thread is terminated).